What piece was Boimler & Rutherford playing at the end of Star Trek: Lower Decks S4E4?
I was watching Lower Decks S4E4 "Something Borrowed, Something Green" last night. At the end of the episode, Boimler and Rutherford dress up as Mozart to resolve a dispute. They try (and hilariously fail) to play a piano duet. Does anybody know which piece they were trying to play?

That's not a Mozart piece, it's the Lower Decks theme song (end credits) badly played on harpsicord, in the style of a Mozart composition.

@Valorum:  answer?

@ThePopMachine - my issue is that it seems obvious to me, but I can't find a lick of evidence to prove it.

@Valorum:  I'm not going to go check, but I dont think it's [citation needed] if it's plainly evident.
